# Iinq equivalent to stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, linq, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a linq statement that is equivalent to a stored procedure I have. What I have does not return any results so I figure must be wrong somewhere.

What I have so far

```
from r in context.View
where ValOne== null ? false : r.ColOne.Equals(ValOne) && 
      ValTwo == null ? false : r.ColTwo.Equals(ValTwo) && 
      (r.ODate >= Start && r.ODate <= End) 
select r
```

What I want to be changed to linq

```
select * from View
Where (@ValOne is null or ColOne = @ValOne)
  and (@ValTwo is null or ColTwo = @ValTwo)
  and (@Start is null or ODate between @Start and @End)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
   from r in context.View
   where (ValOne == null || r.ColOne.Equals(ValOne)) && 
      (ValTwo == null ||r.ColTwo.Equals(ValTwo)) && 
      (Start == null || (r.ODate >= Start && r.ODate <= End)) 
   select r
```

Answer (score 1):

Your sql query return the lines where ValOne is null, ValTwo is null and Start is also null. But your linq query check if ValOne and ValTwo are null but assign false if it's the case wich don't reflect what your sql query is doing.

Can you try :

```
from r in context.View
where ValOne== null ? true: r.ColOne.Equals(ValOne) 
    && ValTwo == null ? true: r.ColTwo.Equals(ValTwo) 
    && (r.ODate >= Start && r.ODate <= End) 
select r
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from r in context.View
where ValOne== null || r.ColOne.Equals(ValOne) && 
      ValTwo == null || r.ColTwo.Equals(ValTwo) && 
      (r.ODate >= Start || r.ODate <= End) 
select r
```